# Error: Invalid hook call - in react-router useHistory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I am using *function component(s)* inside a *class component* and redirecting `onClick` with `react-router` programmatically.

This works:

```
const Child => () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  return (
    <div onClick={() => history.push('/somewhere')}>Click me!</div>
  )
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div><Child /></div>
  }
}
```

But if I have *N* childs, and I do a `.map` like:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  const children = ['a', 'b'].map(Child);
  render() {
    return <div>{children}</div>
  }
}
```

then I get:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

I don't understand why this is a error. If I ignore the rule, as in:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
let history = useHistory();
```

then it works, but am I doing some anti-pattern? I do call the hook inside the body of a function component... but its not being rendered directly as a direct child of a JSX element.

How to use `useHistory` hook in such a scenario? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not do: `<div>
  {[a, b].map((props) => (
    <Child key={props.id} {...props} />
  ))}
</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue :**

is `.map(Child)`, here `Child` is being **considered as** `simple function` and **not as a** `functional component`, and map function is invoking it directly

So as a result react is throwing error : *Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.*

Same as below code snippet :

```js
function square(a) {
  return a*a;
}

console.log([1,2,3].map(square))
```

---

**Solution :**

Change this :

```
children = ['a', 'b'].map(Child);
```

To :

```
children = ['a', 'b'].map((e,i) => <Child key={i}/>); // <--- provide key also
```

**WORKING DEMO :**

[image: Edit #SO-functional-component-issue]

Answer (score 1):

const children = ['a', 'b'].map(Child); not correct replace it with :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  children = ["a", "b"];
  render() {
    return children.map((el, i) => <Child key={i} />);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `<Route exact path='/' render={Content} />` to `<Route exact path='/' component={Content} />` in your App.js file